# IE9 jQuery AJAX GET Error "Unable to Process data"

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery Ajax get request that returns the MVC partialView (returns html). The request works fine in all browser except IE9. IE9 returns error message "Unable to process data".  I am using jQuery version 1.11.4
Here is my AJAX request.

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'AddressTypesListChange',
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'addressType': $("#AddressTypeslist").val(), 'addressId': modelObj, 'type': $('#AddOrEdit').val(), 'companyName': $('#hdncompanyName').val() },
            cache: false,
            dataType: "text",                
            complete: function () {
                alert("AJAX - complete()");
            },
            success: function (data) {                    
                $('#AddEditAddressPlaceHolder').html(data);
            },                
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }                
        });
    }
});
```

I tried the classis XmlHTTP Request and that seems to be working. Here is XMLHttpRequest which works:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('Get', encodeURI('/Address/AddressTypesListChange?addressType=' + $("#AddressTypeslist").val() + '&addressId=' + modelObj + '&type=' + $('#AddOrEdit').val() + '&companyName=' + $('#hdncompanyName').val()));
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    $('#AddEditAddressPlaceHolder').html(xhr.responseText);
                    //alert('User\'s name is ' + xhr.responseText);
                }
                else {
                    alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
```

Here is my partial view that I need to return in result:

```
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls    
@model company.Model.Models.MemberAddressDetails
@{
    SelectListItem[] addressTypes = (SelectListItem[])ViewBag.AddressTypes;
    SelectListItem[] appCountryCodeList = (SelectListItem[])ViewBag.ApplicationCountries;
    var companyName = ViewBag.CompanyName;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyName))
    {
        companyName = Model.CompanyName;
    }
}@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frmWorkAddress", id = "frmWorkAddress" }))
{
    <div class=" row top-buffer-10">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-left">
            @Html.Label("Company Name:", new { @class = "control-label section_detail-title required" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBox("CompanyName", Model.CompanyName, new { @class = "Formcontrol section_detail ", Name = "CompanyName" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => companyName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 padding-Bottom">
            <input type="submit" value="Find Company" class="btn-smallpad btn-success section_detail-font-14" onclick="javascript: submitcompanyfind();" />
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Address", new { @class = "linkbutton padding-left-20" })

        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    //second part

    <div id="hdnDivComapnyfinder" name="hdnDivComapnyfinder" style="display:none">
        <input type="hidden" name="hdnSelectedAddressId" id="hdnSelectedAddressId" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnSelectedcompany" name="hdnSelectedcompany" />
        <div class="row">
            <div id="CompanyList" class=" col-md-12 padding-all">
                <table id="CompanyList_table" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
                    <thead class="CompanyFinder-TableHeader-bgcolor">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="section_detail-title">Select</th>
                            <th class="section_detail-title">Address</th>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div> @*end company list*@
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="button" value="Next" class="btn btn-success " onclick="javascript: passCompanyInfo2mainAddresscontrol();" />
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Address", new { @class = " linkbutton padding-left-20" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#frmWorkAddress").validate({
                    rules: {
                        CompanyName: {
                            required: true
                        },

                    },
                    messages: {
                        CompanyName: {
                            required: "Required"
                        },
                    },
                    errorClass: "validationError",
                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                        if ('console' in window) console.log("in find company");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'FindCompanyList',
                            type: 'Post',
                            data: $(form).serialize(),
                            success: function (data) {
                                var count = Object.keys(data).length;
                                //load the company table rows
                                LoadCompanyList(data);

                                $("#hdnDivComapnyfinder").show();
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

            }); 


            function submitcompanyfind() {

                $("#frmWorkAddress").submit();
            }
            function LoadCompanyList(data) {

                var tablerowshtml;
                $.each(data, function (i) {
                    var companyName = data[i].AddressLabelName;
                    var companywholeAddress = '<b>'+ companyName + '</b><br>' + data[i].AddressLine1 + ' ' + data[i].AddressLine2 + '<br>' + data[i].City + '  ' + data[i].State + ' ' + data[i].PostalCode;
                    var PassAddressId = data[i].AddressId;
                    var companyId = data[i].MemberId;
                    tablerowshtml += "<tr><td><input type='radio' id='SelectCompany' name='SelectCompany' onclick='PassAddressId(" + companyId +"," + PassAddressId + ")' /></td><td class='section_detail'>" + companywholeAddress + '</td></tr>';
                });
                tablerowshtml += "<tr><td><input type='radio' id='SelectCompany' name='SelectCompany' onclick='PassAddressId(0,0)' /></td><td class='section_detail'>" + 'None of the Above</td></tr>';
                $('#CompanyList_table tbody').empty();
                $('#CompanyList_table tbody').append(tablerowshtml);

            }

            function passCompanyInfo2mainAddresscontrol() {

                var selectedCompanyId = $('#hdnSelectedcompany').val();
                var searchedCompanyName = $('#CompanyName').val();
                var selectAddressId = $('#hdnSelectedAddressId').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'GetEditCompanyAddress',
                    type: 'Get',
                    data: { 'companyID': selectedCompanyId, 'companyName': searchedCompanyName, 'AddressId': selectAddressId },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //$('#AddEditAddressPlaceHolder').html("");
                        $('#AddEditAddressPlaceHolder').html(data);
                        $('[name="HomeCountryDropdown"]').trigger('change');
                    },
                    failure: function (errMsg) {
                        alert(errMsg);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        //  alert(xhr.responseText);
                        //  alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });
            }//end function passCompanyInfo2mainAddresscontrol


            function PassAddressId(companyId,addressId)
            {              
                $('#hdnSelectedcompany').val(companyId);
                $('#hdnSelectedAddressId').val(addressId);
            }
        </script>
```

Here is my controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult AddressTypesListChange(string addressType, string addressId, string type,string companyName)
        {
            var memberAddressDetails = new MemberAddressDetails();
            var applicationDetails = MvcApplication.Container.Resolve<IApplicationDetails>();

            var applicationCountries = applicationDetails.GetApplicationCoutries();
            ViewBag.ApplicationCountries = Helper.Convert2SelectListItem(applicationCountries);
            var addressTypes = applicationDetails.GetApplicationCodes(AppCodes.AddressType).Where(x => x.Code != "BULK").ToList();
            ViewBag.AddressTypes = Helper.Convert2SelectListItem(addressTypes);
            ViewBag.AddressType = addressType;

            var memberId = GetKeyValues.GetMemberId();
            var memberAddress = MvcApplication.Container.Resolve<IMemberAddressDetails>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(addressId))
            {
                CustomLogger.LogEvent(EventType.Information, "Call GetAddressDetails to get Address info", CategoryType.General);
                var memberAddressDetailslist = memberAddress.GetAddressDetails(memberId);
                if (memberAddressDetailslist.Results.Success)
                {
                    memberAddressDetails = memberAddressDetailslist.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AddressId==Convert.ToInt32(addressId));
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyName.Trim()))
            {
                memberAddressDetails.CompanyName = companyName;
            }


            if (type == "edit" && memberAddressDetails != null)
            {
                return PartialView("_HomeAddress", memberAddressDetails);
            }
            if (addressType.ToLower().Equals("home") || addressType.ToLower().Equals("university"))
            {

                return PartialView("_HomeAddress", memberAddressDetails);
            }
            else if (addressType.ToLower().Equals("work"))//add partial view
                return PartialView("_EditAddressChangeCompany", memberAddressDetails);
            else
                return PartialView("_EditAddressChangeCompany", memberAddressDetails); //edit partial view
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please post the ActionResult you are calling?  Without knowing what you are returning, it's difficult to know what the issue is.

Knee-jerk reaction is to say change your `dataType:` from `text` to `html`:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'AddressTypesListChange',
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'addressType': $("#AddressTypeslist").val(), 'addressId': modelObj, 'type': $('#AddOrEdit').val(), 'companyName': $('#hdncompanyName').val() },
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",                
        complete: function () {
            alert("AJAX - complete()");
        },
        success: function (data) {                    
            $('#AddEditAddressPlaceHolder').html(data);
        },                
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }                
    });
}
});
```

Without knowing more it's hard to say.

EDIT:  Also, have you considered changing your ajax method from a `'GET'` to `'POST'`, and marking up your ActionResult to reflect that?

EDIT 2:  Consider the following as an update to your `.ajax()` code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'AddressTypesListChange',
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'addressType': $("#AddressTypeslist").val(), 'addressId': modelObj, 'type': $('#AddOrEdit').val(), 'companyName': $('#hdncompanyName').val() },
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html"
})
        .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR )
        {
            $('#AddEditAddressPlaceHolder').html(data);
            //successful call
        })
        .always(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR )
        {
            alert("AJAX - complete()");
            //complete/finally (will run regardless of success or failure)
        })
        .fail(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR )
        {  
            //In this case, jqXHR represents the errorThrown.
            alert(jqXHR);
        });
```

Overall, it seems as if your syntax may be at fault, as it's rather unlikely that the code would work in other browsers but not in IE9 were this a return data issue.  As per the `.ajax()` spec, the `complete`, `success`, and `error` callbacks have been deprecated as of jQuery 1.8, with the preferred method being the above Promise-style method chaining.

jQuery spec: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I have tried changing dataType from text to html without any success. I also tried the POST Vs GET and no success. The odd thing is that I tried the classic JS XmlHTTPRequest and that works.. But we are using jQusy Ajax on so many places, it is hard to changes all that to XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using as well?  As per the jQuery spec here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  , .success() and .complete() have been deprecated as of 1.8.x.  Further, the signature for your success method is off.  I will edit my response.

Comment: Hi, I have added the XMLHttpRequest code that is working and also added my partialview that I need to return and also my controller action. I am using the jQury version 1.11.4

Comment: I tried your code in Edit2 and I still fails and throws the same error.

Comment: At this point, and having seen the partial view, I think your problem is with the actual HTML you are returning.  PartialViews (to the best of my knowledge) should not include <script> within them, so I'd consider pulling that out into an external .js file, or at the very least revisiting the layout of that partial.  Without delving deep into your code, it's going to be very difficult to figure out exactly what is wrong.

Comment: I have removed the script from the return html and result is still the same. I just return the html code only. But still no difference